# terminal output for Rails app produces double requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app generates double requests with every page load, and I'm not able to diagnose the source of the problem. Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266020/rails-app-logging-duplicate-requests) suggest removing all blank/self-referencing `href`s and running `rake assets:clean` - but neither has any impact.

Both of these requests are identical, save for timestamps and the `as` part of the controller action processing. The first request says `Processing by TradesController#index as HTML` whereas the second says `Processing by TradesController#index as */*`

Has anyone else dealt with this, and if so, how did you fix it?

```
Started GET "/swaps" for 2600:1700:ba01:ff10:cc31:d814:a204:d70e at 2020-02-23 14:32:25 -0800
Processing by TradesController#index as HTML
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_requester_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_requester_id", 1]]
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_recipient_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_recipient_id", 1]]
Rendering trades/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered trades/_trades_menu.html.erb (0.5ms)
CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_recipient_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_recipient_id", 1]]
Rendered trades/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_recipient_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_recipient_id", 1]]
Transaction Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "transactions"."archived_by_recipient" = $2  [["recipient_id", 1], ["archived_by_recipient", false]]
Transaction Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."sender_id" = $1 AND (state = 'approved' OR state = 'force_flipped' OR state = 'payment_sent' OR state = 'payment_declined' OR state = 'passed'  OR state = 'paid'  OR state = 'refunded'  OR state = 'shipped' OR state = 'received' OR state = 'not_received' OR state = 'unpaid' OR state = 'ignored' OR state = 'declined') AND "transactions"."archived_by_sender" = $2  [["sender_id", 1], ["archived_by_sender", false]]
PaymentTransfer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payment_transfers".* FROM "payment_transfers" WHERE "payment_transfers"."user_id" = $1 AND (user_id = 1 AND read = FALSE)  [["user_id", 1]]
CACHE Transaction Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "transactions"."archived_by_recipient" = $2  [["recipient_id", 1], ["archived_by_recipient", false]]
CACHE Transaction Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."sender_id" = $1 AND (state = 'approved' OR state = 'force_flipped' OR state = 'payment_sent' OR state = 'payment_declined' OR state = 'passed'  OR state = 'paid'  OR state = 'refunded'  OR state = 'shipped' OR state = 'received' OR state = 'not_received' OR state = 'unpaid' OR state = 'ignored' OR state = 'declined') AND "transactions"."archived_by_sender" = $2  [["sender_id", 1], ["archived_by_sender", false]]
CACHE PaymentTransfer Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "payment_transfers".* FROM "payment_transfers" WHERE "payment_transfers"."user_id" = $1 AND (user_id = 1 AND read = FALSE)  [["user_id", 1]]
(1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "messages" ON "messages"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "messages"."user_id" WHERE ((conversations.sender_id = 1 OR conversations.receiver_id = 1)) AND (messages.user_id != 1 AND read = FALSE)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (9.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 48.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  COMMIT

Started GET "/swaps" for 2600:1700:ba01:ff10:cc31:d814:a204:d70e at 2020-02-23 14:32:26 -0800
Processing by TradesController#index as */*
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_requester_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_requester_id", 1]]
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_recipient_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_recipient_id", 1]]
Rendering trades/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered trades/_trades_menu.html.erb (0.6ms)
CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_recipient_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_recipient_id", 1]]
Rendered trades/index.html.erb within layouts/application (27.1ms)
CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" WHERE "trades"."trade_recipient_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved_at" IS NULL  [["trade_recipient_id", 1]]
Transaction Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "transactions"."archived_by_recipient" = $2  [["recipient_id", 1], ["archived_by_recipient", false]]
Transaction Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."sender_id" = $1 AND (state = 'approved' OR state = 'force_flipped' OR state = 'payment_sent' OR state = 'payment_declined' OR state = 'passed'  OR state = 'paid'  OR state = 'refunded'  OR state = 'shipped' OR state = 'received' OR state = 'not_received' OR state = 'unpaid' OR state = 'ignored' OR state = 'declined') AND "transactions"."archived_by_sender" = $2  [["sender_id", 1], ["archived_by_sender", false]]
PaymentTransfer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payment_transfers".* FROM "payment_transfers" WHERE "payment_transfers"."user_id" = $1 AND (user_id = 1 AND read = FALSE)  [["user_id", 1]]
CACHE Transaction Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "transactions"."archived_by_recipient" = $2  [["recipient_id", 1], ["archived_by_recipient", false]]
CACHE Transaction Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."sender_id" = $1 AND (state = 'approved' OR state = 'force_flipped' OR state = 'payment_sent' OR state = 'payment_declined' OR state = 'passed'  OR state = 'paid'  OR state = 'refunded'  OR state = 'shipped' OR state = 'received' OR state = 'not_received' OR state = 'unpaid' OR state = 'ignored' OR state = 'declined') AND "transactions"."archived_by_sender" = $2  [["sender_id", 1], ["archived_by_sender", false]]
CACHE PaymentTransfer Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "payment_transfers".* FROM "payment_transfers" WHERE "payment_transfers"."user_id" = $1 AND (user_id = 1 AND read = FALSE)  [["user_id", 1]]
(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "messages" ON "messages"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "messages"."user_id" WHERE ((conversations.sender_id = 1 OR conversations.receiver_id = 1)) AND (messages.user_id != 1 AND read = FALSE)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (8.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 152ms (Views: 116.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Look at your browser's network monitor and make sure two requests are being made. I know you've stated that you already tried to remove all self-referencing links, but did you check any CSS `url()` with blank parameters or anything similar? Self-referencing probably still is the main cause.

Comment: checked the network monitor and i'm not seeing any doubled assets. the double request still shows in terminal. how...odd?

Comment: Sharing a bit of your code could be helpful ...

Comment: @ClemensKofler i would love to, but i don't even know what code to share. it's not like this is an "error" with a stacktrace that goes neatly back to some line

Comment: For starters, you should share 1) the view where you're calling/linking to the `/swaps` URL and 2) the controller that's rendering said URL (apparently the `TradesController`).

Comment: You could add a `byebug` to your controller and try to understand what is calling it twice via caller.